# wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) rails 6.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6.1

I check current page with rails 5.1.2 and no problem, but rails 6.1.1 error wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

```
<% if current_page?(controller: 'categories', action: 'new')%>
    <%= link_to "&larr;".html_safe  + @shop.name, shops_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
<%else%>
    <%= link_to "&larr; Volver".html_safe, new_shop_category_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" %>
<%end%>
```

My first solution is

```
<% if controller_name == 'categories' && action_name == 'new'%>
```

but I would like to know the problem

any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: What ruby version are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an answer for you, but I ran into the same issue.
It was working fine when my app was running on Rails 6.0.6 and ruby 2.4.7, but it was not working after I upgraded ruby to 3.1.2 anymore...

Comment: I encountered the same issue when upgrading Ruby from 2.6.8 to 3.0.6. Rails set at 6.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a hash instead of keyword arguments:

```
current_page?({controller: 'categories', action: 'new'})
```